# Microsoft Face API in Android

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am using the Cognitive-Face-Android sample app found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Android).

All are working except when I use the Identification Button. I was able to add a Group and also able to add Persons within the group and they get saved.  However, when i start to add the images for Person A, emulator will show the image but when I click Save, the image did not get added to Person A. It is not getting saved.

Is there anything I need to change in the code?

[image]

Comment: A minor bug related to person group is fixed not long ago. Would you please have a try on the latest code? https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Android/pull/19

Comment: Thank you Xuan.  I downloaded the package from github only last May 12, 2017.  Was the fix to the person group done after May 12, 2017?

Comment: @Xuan - I downloaded the latest sample app which corrected the endpoint but the issue about group is still an issue.  When I try to add a Face image to a Person's name, it does not get saved. Kindly advise. Thanks.

Comment: @Xuan - I downloaded the latest version of the sample app today(June 14) since I noticed that I changed something in the Client Library recently.  However, the issue on saving a face image to a Person's name under group is still not working.  Please advise what I need to do. Thanks.